# BufferedReader readline() not reading CSV line by line for long rows

Tags: java, csv, bufferedreader, readline, bufferedwriter

I am using BufferedReader to read from a CSV file which is in the form
"item1","item2","item3". I am using the readline() function to get each row and then use String.split() to separate each item. I notice that when I have a really long row, it splits the row and treats as 2 separate rows. I tried using BufferedWriter.newline() instead of putting "\n" after each row, but that does not solve the issue. Also, when I open up the .csv file in Notepad++ i see that the line is being split at the same point where readline() is going to a newline, but when I open it in the traditional notepad I see that the data is how I meant it to be i.e each row in a new line.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/newData.csv"));
String line = "";
while((line=br.readLine()) != null){
   System.out.println(line+"\n\n");
}
```

Comment: You should double check the content of your file, in binary if need be.

Comment: Hmmm, if Notepad++ and Notepad are seeing line breaks differently, then perhaps it's something to do with platform-dependent line breaks? I thought that `BufferedReader` took that into account though...

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel use something like csvReader

Comment: Are you processing quotes correctly? If a cellv value starts with a quote, everything until the closing quote is part of the cell, ignoring line breaks. The code you've posted is completely meaningless.

Comment: Thank you for your replies guys. @ScaryWombat used the opencsv-2.4 from code.google. Worked like a charm!